# Carga parcial de elementos con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

En mi HTML, quiero cargar solo una sección `<main>` sin recargar la pagina completa. Para ello estoy utilizando `load()` de JQuery al hacer clic en unos enlaces que hacen de menú, y en principio funciona.

El Html del nav:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="index" href="index.html"><i class="bi bi-house-door-fill">Start</i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="contact" href="#"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill">Contact</i></a></li>
    <li><a id="proyects" href="#"><i class="bi bi-file-spreadsheet-fill">Proyects</i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="about" href="#"><i class="bi bi-file-person-fill">About</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main></main>
```

El codigo JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#proyects').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("main").empty();
    $("main").load('proyects.html', function () {
      $("#photos").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $("#photos").animate({
          opacity: "1",
        });
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#about').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("main").empty();
    $("main").load('home.html');
    return false;
  });
});
```

El problema me viene cuando le doy varias veces. Con cada clic es más y más lento. Además, si hago clic en otro de los enlaces para cargar otra sección, esta se carga, pero dejan de funcionar todos mostrando el contenido solo una vez.

Es decir, si doy clic al mismo enlace, puedo repetir las veces que quiera para recargar la sección, pero cada vez es mucho mas lento.
Por otro lado, si doy a un enlace y luego a otro, cada uno se carga correctamente, pero dejan de funcionar y el menu queda bloqueado.

Las paginas que quiero cargar son html completo:

```
 <main id="proyectsdiv">
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Let me show you something about my work</h1>
  </section>

  <div id="photos">
   <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="photo" src="images/ciervo.jpg" class="d-block w- 
    100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="photo" src="images/fox.jpg" class="d-block w-100" 
    alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="photo" src="images/islandia.jpg" class="d-block w- 
     100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs- 
     target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs- 
   target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
  </div>
 </div>


   </main>
   <script  src="javascript.js/loadMain.js"></script>
   <script  src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"> 
   </script>
```

Comment: ¿home.html y proyects.html que contienen? Son páginas html con head, body, scripts etc o son páginas parciales, es decir sin head ni body n iscripts? Podrías ponerlas? La lentitud debe ser por el *fadein*

Comment: @Juan Carlos Guibovich son paginas html completas. Reedito la pregunta para mostrar la de proyect.php.

Comment: Ademas, veo que si en vez de un html completo, dejo solo el contenido de la etiqueta <main>, se carga bien, pero como tiene scripts asociados dejan de funcionar. Estos mismos scripts estan tambien en la pagina desde la cual los quiero cargar pero no funcionan. Ademas, visual studio code me manda el mensaje **Live Reload is not possible without a head or body tag**.

Comment: Reedito para lo último que he dejado en los html. Ya no son documentos completos, sino que he dejado solo la etiqueta main y los scripts. Parece que funciona aunque con cada clic la carga se ralentiza mas. El primer clic carga rápido, y luego con cada clic se va retrasando como 1 seg que se va acumulando

Comment: Los scripts también podrías sacarlos o pasarlos al principal de modo tal que evites la carga de esos scripts en cada load. Si bien los.scripts pudieran ralentizar el tiempo, estos serían los mismo por cada load, pero dices que se incrementan a medida que das el clic. Ahora los tiempos pueden aumentar si tienes el main también en esas páginas porque estarías cargando por cada clic varios main el principal y el que ya estuviera productonde un load.

Comment: Si el principal tiene ```main``` y las páginas que cargas también tienes ```main```, el tercer ```clic`` supuestamente haria un ```load``` para el  ```main``` principal y el ```main``` que cargó con el ```load``` del segundo ```clic```, y así sucesivamente. Esa podría ser la explicacion que aumente el tiempo a medida que vas dando ```clic```. Asegúrate que los html no tengan la misma etiqueta que utilizas para el ```load``` porque podrías tener resultados medios raros.

Comment: El ```fadin``` Debería ser solo para ```$("#photos .active")```

Comment: Correcto, he quitado las etiquetas main y los scripts dejando solo los de la pagina principal. he readaptado el JS para que las animaciones no se pisen y para que solo haya una etiqueta main para cargar. Asi funciona correctamente. Solo puedo votarte los comentarios, como no está como respuesta tengo opcion de aceptarla. Muchas gracias

Comment: Voy a colocar los comentarios como una respuesta

Comment: veo que llamas a la etiqueta main, pero al cargar tambien tienes una etiqueta main, asi que eso hace un loop que enreda el navegador, por eso te mensione que sea un id y no una etiqueta